# Bring information from cart into edit product page?

Tags: cart, edit

All my items in the cart have an edit button. Upon clicking that edit button I would like to bring information from the cart to the edit page so I can display some things.

EDIT**
In the cart all my products are loaded in one by one with their attributes.
Each product has it's own $areasJson which is a php variable that is a long string which I use to create a custom image for each item.

However when I click the edit button it brings me to the simple product page of that item but I lose the $areasJson information because I don't know how to bring it with me.

Comment: What are that "some things", you want to display ?

Comment: Could you explain the question clearly?

Comment: Hey I clarified my question :)

Answer (score 1):

On clicking edit in shopping cart page it's showing the product's view.phtml file the only difference is instead of showing 'Add to cart' (frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml) it's displaying 'Update Cart'(frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml). So you can pass the passed parameter from the cart could be fetched in updatecart.phtml.

If you explain the question clearly like what parameter you need to fetch in the edit page, I could work and see.

Comment: Moreover, it has a different `.ptml` file which means it can be used for 'custom information' that @CodingMageSheen wants. Also, you can pass url Params.

Comment: The problem for me is that I'm not sure if my company wants me to pass the long string data that has a lot of info in it through the url. It's in a php variable, is there a way I can shove it into an object / array then pass it through the url and open it on the other side? (aka edit page)